# Change Bundler installation path to normal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

In order to fix something unrelated to this, I did a `bundle install --path vendor/cache`. Now every time I use `bundle install`, the gems are being installed into 'vendor/cache'. How can I revert this so that a `bundle install` installs the gems into the normal directory?

**Update**
`bundle install --system` makes no difference.

Answer (score 11):

In project directory after this command `bundle install --path vendor/cache` `bundler` create config file in `.bundle/config` that contain `bundler` config:

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/cache
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

Delete or edit this file for you need.

`--path` options. `Bundler` will remember this value ***for future installs on this machine***

> You can specify this setting when installing via bundle install
>   /path/to/bundle. Bundler will remember where you installed the
>   dependencies to on a particular machine for future installs, loads,
>   setups, etc.

Also, you might want to check out `~/.bundle/config` for the `BUNDLE_PATH` setting.

Comment: I deleted the file but `bundle install` still installs into `vendor/cache`.

Comment: i think you do something wrong. This normal bundler usage and this work for other bundler users.

Comment: Well I deleted the`.bundle` folder, run `rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/ .bundle/ Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install`. The gems are all in `vendor/cache` again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @LinusAn Last attempt, you can try use `bundle env` to view paths and bundle configuration. This will tell you where the path configuration is set.

Comment: Ok, the paths I get back are `GEM_HOME /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0` and `GEM_PATH /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global`.

Comment: so try require default path like `bundle install --path ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0`. This should save settings  for future.

Answer (score 5):

This worked/was enough for me, when I discovered that the `PATH` was set in my project only.

Check the project's config file at: `.bundle/config`

Remove necessary files in your project:

```
rm .bundle/config
rm Gemfile.lock
rm -rf vendor
```

And then recreate Gemfile.lock:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 3):

Following these steps from the bundler.io website solved the problem:

```
# remove project-specific settings 
rm -rf .bundle/  
# remove project-specific cached gems and repos 
rm -rf vendor/cache/  
# remove the saved resolve of the Gemfile 
rm -rf Gemfile.lock  
# uninstall the rubygems-bundler and open_gem gems 
rvm gemset use global 
# if using rvm 
gem uninstall rubygems-bundler open_gem  
# try to install one more time bundle install
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a path for your local app. It is `vendor/cache` in your case because you changed it. You can check the path (see path section):

```
bundle env
```

The solution is:

```
bundle install --path $BUNDLE_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf vendor/

bundle install --path $GEM_HOME
```